# Draw line between two distinct points

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have in matlab, e.g. `plot (sin(-pi:0.1:pi));` which plots the curve quite nicely. Now I want to connect two points, namely the one which e.g. equals -1 (=`asin(-1)`) and the end-point at pi.

How can I connect these points with a single line?

Note: the `sin` is just a quick'ndirty sample. Perhaps there exists better functions, but I just wanted to have a wide range set of values (which I have at the very ending - not as function, but as data points).

Comment: check out [`annotation`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the `line` function in matlab like so:

```
X = linspace(-pi,pi,100); % //use linspace to make sure the last point is pi
x = [asin(-1) pi]; % //define the set of points which define your line
y=[-1 eps]; % //Use epsilon here since sin(pi) is approx epsilon (The lines will look more connected )
plot (X,sin(X)); % //it is important to plot both X and Y, otherwise the x-axis will be wrong
hold on;line(x,y,'Color','r');
```

This produces: 
[image]